# Using os.path.dirname on windows path

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

I'm using a linux machine which run a python 2.7.
I want to use `os.path.dirname()` to get the parent directory of the file's full path (not from this machine), for example:
`C:\\documents and settings\\Dan\\yada\\1.txt` =>
Will result in `C:\\documents and settings\\Dan\\yada`

But surprise, I get empty string instead.

Anybody can explain why and how to solve it?

Comment: Linux doesn't know a c:\\

Comment: Pretty difficult guess with no code to show how you're calling it, etc. What is the result of `os.path.exists(path_you_passed_to_dirname)`? How are you connected to the Windows machine? There are too many unaddressed things here that could be wrong.

Comment: @Simon More correctly, on linux, `C:\documents and settings\Dan\yada\1.txt` is a valid filename (as in, you can have a `/home/dan/C:\documents and settings\Dan\yada\1.txt`. So `os.path.dirname("C:\\documents and settings\\Dan\\yada\\1.txt")` is `""` (empty string) as it is only a filename, in exactly the same way `os.path.dirname("1.txt")` is also `""`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `ntpath` instead:

```
>>> import ntpath
>>> ntpath.dirname('C:\\documents and settings\\Dan\\yada\\1.txt')
'C:\\documents and settings\\Dan\\yada'
```

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html):

> Since different operating systems have different path name conventions, there are several versions of this module in the standard library. The [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) module is always the path module suitable for the operating system Python is running on, and therefore usable for local paths. However, you can also import and use the individual modules if you want to manipulate a path that is *always* in one of the different formats. They all have the same interface:
>
> - `posixpath` for UNIX-style paths
> - `ntpath` for Windows paths
> - [`macpath`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/macpath.html#module-macpath) for old-style MacOS paths
> - `os2emxpath` for OS/2 EMX paths